# Get product Custom option value in event sales_quote_add_item

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

Bellow is my code I call sales_quote_add_item to change product price acording to custom option. I want it on admin add to cart.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_add_item">
         <observer name="customprice" instance="Smartupworld\Core\Observer\Admin\Price" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Here I php observer

```
<?php
namespace Smartupworld\Core\Observer\Admin;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Price implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        //$product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');

        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');           
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        $customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($item->getProduct());

        $options = $item->getProductOptions();        
        if (isset($options['options']) && !empty($options['options'])) {        
            foreach ($options['options'] as $option) {
                echo 'Title: ' . $option['label'] . '<br />';
                echo 'ID: ' . $option['option_id'] . '<br />';
                echo 'Type: ' . $option['option_type'] . '<br />';
                echo 'Value: ' . $option['option_value'] . '<br />' . '<br />';
                //$title[] = $option['label'];
            }
        }
        $price = 100;
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
```

I can't get option value on price.php file. I want to change price acording to option values. But I can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

using this I get the option datas:

```
$options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
$customOptions = $options['options'];
$title = array();
if (!empty($customOptions)) 
{
    foreach ($customOptions as $key=>$option) 
    {
    echo 'Title: ' . $option['label'] . '<br />';
    echo 'ID: ' . $option['option_id'] . '<br />';
    echo 'Type: ' . $option['option_type'] . '<br />';
    echo 'Value: ' . $option['option_value'] . '<br />' . '<br />';    
    $title[] = $option['label'];
        //$title[] = $option['option_value'];
    }

    //$cart->getquote()->getItemById($item->getItemId())->setOptions($options);
    //$cart->save();
}
```